# How to send long html as email using Mailgun in Parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, mailgun

I'm able to send emails from Parse cloud code using the below code. I'm facing formatting issues when long html templates are involved. Is there anyway I can call a html file without having to copy chunks of html code?

If there any website to format the html code, which can be easily copy pasted?

```
 Mailgun.sendEmail({
  to: email,
  from: "XYZ <hello@xyz.com>",
  subject: "Welcome to XYZ",  
  text: "Hello " + name + ",\n\n Welcome to XYZ!",
  html: "<html> <b> Awesome restaurants around you </html>"
 }, {
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse);
    console.log("Email sent to " + email);
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    console.error(httpResponse);
    console.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used this website to convert huge chunks of HTML into Javascript.

http://htmltojavascript.com/